# How to efficiently create lag variable using Stata

Tags: stata

I have panel data (**time:** date, **name:** ticker). I want to create 10 lags for variables `x` and `y`. Now I create each lag variable one by one using the following code:

```
by ticker: gen lag1 = x[_n-1]
```

However, this looks messy.

Can anyone tell me how can I create lag variables more efficiently, please?

Shall I use a loop or does Stata have a more efficient way of handling this kind of problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Robert has shown you the streamlined way of doing it. For completion, here is the "traditional", boring way:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 2

gen id = _n
expand 20

bysort id: gen time = _n
tsset id time

set seed 12345
gen x = runiform()
gen y = 10 * runiform()

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

// "traditional" loop
forvalues i = 1/10 {
     gen x_`i' = L`i'.x
     gen y_`i' = L`i'.y
}

list, sepby(id)
```

And a combination:

```
// a combination
foreach v in x y {
    tsrevar L(1/10).`v'
    rename (`r(varlist)') `v'_#, addnumber
}
```

If the purpose is to create lagged variables to use them in some estimation, know you can use time-series operators within many estimation commands, directly; that is, no need to create the lagged variables in the first place. See `help tsvarlist`.

Answer (score 5):

You can loop to do this but you can also take advantage of `tsrevar` to generate temporary lagged variables. If you need permanent variables, you can use `rename group` to rename them.

```
clear
set obs 2
gen id = _n
expand 20
bysort id: gen time = _n
tsset id time
set seed 12345
gen x = runiform()
gen y = 10 * runiform()
tsrevar L(1/10).x
rename (`r(varlist)') x_#, addnumber
tsrevar L(1/10).y
rename (`r(varlist)') y_#, addnumber
```

Note that if you are doing this to calculate a statistic on a rolling window, check out `tsegen` (from SSC)