# how to use tsrevar to create lag variable using stata

Tags: stata

I got a panel data (time: date  name: ticker). I want to create upto 10 lagged variables for `x`. So I use the following code.

```
tsrevar L(1/10).x
rename (`r(varlist)') x_#, addnumber
```

Because my data is in hourly frequency, and only observation during the daytime. Using the code above, the first observation for each trading day is missing.
My alternative solution is:

```
by ticker: gen lag1 = return[_n-1]
```

Then, I have to copy and paste this code 10 times, which looks very messy. Could anyone teach me how to solve this problem please

Comment: I solved this using loop, but please let me know if there is any better solutions

Comment: Overlaps with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234458/how-to-efficiently-create-lag-variable-using-stata Please don't repeat very similar questions.

Comment: Of course the lag of the first observation of the day is missing if your observations are hourly and trading is a daytime activity. Your solution will use values from the preceding day for the lags. For the first 10 periods of the day, the values will come from the last 10 periods of the preceding day. If that's what you want, just redefine time using `bysort ticker (hour): gen period = _n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my "10-minute guess" given I don't actually work with anything finer than a daily periodicity.

Stata has no **hourly** display format that I know of. One way to achieve what you want is using the `delta()` option when you `tsset` the data.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

// an "hour-by-hour" time series which really has millisecond format
set obs 25

gen double t = _n*1000*60
format %tcDDmonCCYY_HH:MM:SS:.sss t

set seed 3129745
gen ret = runiform()

list, sep(0)

*----- what you want? -----

// 1000*60 milliseconds conform 1 hour
tsset t, delta((1000*60)) 

// one way
tsrevar L(1/2).ret
rename (`r(varlist)') ret_#, addnumber

// two other ways
gen  ret1 = L.ret
gen  ret11 = ret[_n-1]

// check
assert ret_1 == ret1
assert ret_1 == ret11

list, sep(0)
```

`tsset` also has a `generic` option, and `delta()` itself has several specifications. Take a look and test, to see if you find a better fit.

(You mention an "hourly frequency" but you don't give example data with the specifics. There really is no way to know for sure what you're dealing with.)